# Topology Problem. Surface not smooth

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, topology

I tried reducing the number of lines with this method, but the result was that the surface became jagged. I want the surface to remain smooth.

[image: "jagged" surface]
[image: the topology line i made]

I did another experiment, but the results were still not optimal.
2nd experiment :

[image: 2nd experiment]
[image: but a little bit better]

[image]

Comment: Please do send the file, with this representative chunk of your mesh,  to make it simpler for folks to demonstrate alternatives.. follow the instructions on https://blend-exchange.com/, and paste the link into your post.

Comment: Oh okay. I just added it. @RobinBetts

Comment: Thanks. Looking ahead, do you intend to  repeat this strut around the wheel, or is it going to remain on its own, as provided?

Comment: oh, I'll make it 5 Spokes. I've tried it with Radial Array. It worked, just a few adjustments needed. @RobinBetts

Comment: I think the repeat, strangely, will make the topo easier. You can have more, evenly spaced, loops on the inner ring, to soak up the bevels on the struts.

Comment: Have you tried to turn this way? https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvCVN.png

Comment: Maybe you should add more vertices to the cylinder, like 64 instead of 32, it would make things easier

Comment: ahh, i will try this. Thanks @lemon

Comment: @RobinBetts umm... I still don't understand :( . But i will try another advice on the comment..

Comment: Ah right, I haven't tried this one yet @moonboots

Comment: @moonboots, (Far be it from me)..I think it would be easier still,  if the number of segments was divisible by 5. Maybe 65? Opar: On the previous comment, you could wrap  some of those tied-off bevels around the rim, between duplicate spokes. Will try to get to it, unless the master moonboots demo's first.

Comment: I think making the "top" part without guessing the circle vertex count should be easier. You'll always be able to make this part circular afterward, @RobinBetts

Comment: @Robin Betts oh yes maybe 65, it depends on where the branches are supposed to extrude

Comment: @lemon True.. my (possibly faulty) approach wouldn't be a 
guess, though .. it would be a (then discarded) block-out. A sketch.

Comment: FI, I gave it a try and ended up with 50 vertices for the circular part.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this kind of topology, where the mesh goes around the corners:

[image]

I suggest you don't matter of the circular part at the begining, as you can always make it circular at the end using loop tools.

Basically, that means you've a quad at each corner of the mesh, and either open it in order to turn around it (in green) or prolongate it to have the 'bevel like' edges (in blue).

[image]

Here the result in the blend file (but I've not really worked on the parts that are not shown in the above image).

[image]